# I would like to disable recaptcha google script from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

I made a wordpress site and installed the divi theme. So far, so great. I run my website on Gtmetrix and I have found that recaptcha from google is activated. I couldn't find the code responsible for this to remove it.
I would like to ask if there is a way to block this script from my whole website. I mean a turn around.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LeRt98UAAAAAKkE3Tp1KWhkueb7fyKQz1sbBts6&#038;ver=5.4.1'></script>
```

If you need the website to check, facmaroc.com , not sure if it's allowed to post a website link. Moderator, sorry if this is not allowed.

Cordially,

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to divi theme. Check settings. Reference: https://bestwebsoft.com/recaptcha-and-divi-compatibility/

Answer (score 0):

I am back,
I found a little solution. I am sure it's not the perfect one, but it fixed my issue.
This plugin helped me fixe the issue: Asset CleanUp: Page Speed Booster